# Runnning a Job in Apache Flink standalone mode on Zeppelin I have this error "TooLongFrameException: Adjusted frame length exceeds"

Tags: docker, akka, apache-flink, apache-zeppelin

I'm trying to run a simple job in apache flink using Zeppelin.
I have created a docker container with zeppelin 0.8.0 running. In the same container I have runnning apache flink 1.6.1. When I run the job using the flink interpreter that zeppelin has by default, works good and I can see the result of the job. But when I do it in my own interpreter with flink 1.6.1 running in standalone mode, I have the following error:

[image: job in zepplin]

Configuration of my interpreter:

[image: interpreter]

Properties setted in flink-conf.yaml

```
jobmanager.rpc.address: 0.0.0.0
jobmanager.rpc.port: 6134

jobmanager.heap.size: 1024m
taskmanager.heap.size: 1024m
taskmanager.numberOfTaskSlots: 1
parallelism.default: 1
```

The error I get in the flink log (that's means flink receive the job from zeppelin):

```
2019-01-18 15:30:53,761 WARN  
akka.remote.transport.netty.NettyTransport - Remote connection to 
[/172.17.0.2:54842] failed with org.apache.flink.shaded.akka.org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.frame.TooLongFrameException: Adjusted frame length exceeds 10485760: 2147549189 - discarded
```

I know akka has the frame size messages setted 10485760b by default, but I'm receiving this value 2147549189 that is too big. I tried modifying this property akka.framesize: 10485760b in flink-conf.yaml but I can't put that huge size, doesn't have too much sense to me.

Comment: Have you ever resolved this problem or how did you circumvent the problem? I am also working with Flink and Zeppelin at the moment and have the same problem. I guess that "Connect to existing process" is wrong here isn't it?

Comment: I don't remember exactly which was the real problem, but I remember I couldn't do anything to fix it because it was something internal in Zeppelin (something related to the versions that runs on zeppellin).  
If you check the releases, honestly they are very poor. They went from the release 0.8 to 0.8.1 in 1 year.
So I came with another plan and start to use Jupyter Notebook instead, it is a similiar tool, very powerfull and easy to use. But I didn't try flink on this one.